# Docker containers for asp.net core project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm new to docker and I created a docker file for my asp.net core test project
[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anznQ.png)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExampleApp.dll"]
```

and then I creat a docker image

```
docker build . -t apress/exampleapp -f Dockerfile
```

and then I create a container from that Image

```
docker create -p 3000:80 --name exampleApp3000 apress/exampleapp
```

and it worked successfully
and now when I try to change the index file in my project and try to copy thif file to container with this command

```
docker cp ./Views/Home/Index.cshtml exampleApp3000:/app/Views/Home/
```

the **no such directory** message appears

**note** I'm using windows 10 and the target framework for container is linux

```
<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to copy the file and the error `no such directory` happen you miss file name in the destination, so it should be.

```
docker cp ./Views/Home/Index.cshtml exampleApp3000:/app/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

Also will recomend to run with host mounting file.

```
docker run -it -p 3000:80 -v HOST_PATH/Index.cshtml:/app/Views/Home/Index.cshtml --name exampleApp3000 apress/exampleapp
```

[docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories](https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c)

Comment: when I add Index.chtml the error Error: No such container:path: exampleApp3000:\app\Views\Home

 appears

Comment: so this path `\app\Views\Home` is not exist in your contianer.